# Why request is sent twice?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I create a rxjs application. It just gets a list of users from the server. However it does it twice. I use `share()` operator, but that doesn't solve the problem.

Please explain to me why this is happening. I don't need a solution, I just need an explanation.

Live example [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/focused-voice-wkl74c?file=%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html%3A9%2C1).

Controller code here:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';
import { map, share } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  users$: Observable<any> = ajax(
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
  ).pipe(
    map((res: any) => res?.response),
    share()
  );
}
```

Template code:

```
<div *ngIf="users$ | async">
  <li *ngFor="let item of users$ | async">
    {{ item.name }}
  </li>

  <li *ngFor="let item of users$ | async">
    {{ item.name }}
  </li>

  <li *ngFor="let item of users$ | async">
    {{ item.name }}
  </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Believe that the reason why emit twice was due to the observable(s) for the `*ngFor` was the *late subscriber*.

You should look for [`shareReplay`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay) operator.

From the [documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay#why-use-sharereplay),

> It may also be valuable in situations where you know you will have late subscribers to a stream that need access to previously emitted values.

```
import { shareReplay } from 'rxjs';

users$: Observable<any> = ajax(
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
).pipe(
  map((res: any) => res?.response),
  shareReplay()
);
```

With this, the observable will be executed for the first and only time and share to the late subscriber(s).

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-6bdt11?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Answer (score 0):

why using ajax angular has its own library `@angular/common/http`
use it like this :

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

in the constructor function

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient){}
```

now create method and observable of type `users[]`

```
users!:Observable<users[]>;

getUsers(){
 this.users = this.http.get<users[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
}
```

finally you need to call the method inside ngOnInit life cycle or inside
the constructor

```
ngOnInit(){ 
  this.getUsers()
}
```

now every thing should work as should be